# c# WPF MVVM how to retrieve all selecteditems from multiselect listbox and show in textblock

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

c# wpf MVVM way : I have a listbox with itemsource set to a table via entity framework. the listbox allows multiselect. Now i want to retrieve all the selecteditems from the listbox and then show them in a textblock.

Comment: any effort from your side, to achieve this?

Comment: How do you expect to show all selected items in a single textblock?? Please post some code you have tried, or people may **find it unclear**.

Comment: binding SelectedItems to a ObservableCollection and foreach (var item in Collection){ string  = string + item.tostring() }

Comment: You already said it. Now start coding.